# Differential proofs

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, differential

We had an assignment for the past week, to prove some equations which I had no idea that could actually be proved, since I was kind of taking them for granted. The professor did not check them anyway he just moved on. These are :

- $d(x \pm y) = dx \pm dy$
- $\Delta(x \pm y) = \Delta x \pm \Delta y$
- $x \pm y = \int dx \pm \int dy$
- $d(xy) = x\, dy + y\, dx$
- $d(x/y) = (y\, dx - x\, dy)/y^2$

How can these be proved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the third identity (with the integral signs) to see that it matches your intent; the left-hand side was missing in the original post.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang but the original post was how it was assigned to us. Now it does not really make sense

Comment: I see...if you're positive there's no error in the original, please feel free to re-combine the second and third lines (though I can't imagine how $\Delta(x \pm y) = \int dx + \int dy$ is supposed to be interpreted).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I know  I am of the same opinion and that's somthing that I feel like I don't understand but I thought that since I am a beginner maybe there is something I need to grasp, but I don't doubt that our professor could be wrong, since he hasn't uploaded the final slides yet to check it Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the operations of classical (as opposed to [non-standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis)) calculus act on *functions* (which have a formal, set-theoretic definition), not on *variables*. Classically, however, mathematical notation indicates functional relationships by using variables as templates, e.g., writing $y = x^{2}$ to indicate the relationship of squaring, leaving the reader to interpret $x$ as an arbitrary input (or "element of the domain") and $y$ as the output.

Assuming you're in a beginning calculus course (probably for engineers or scientists...?), I'd recommend interpreting your formulas as follows, for arbitrary differentiable functions $f$ and $g$:

- $(f \pm g)' = f' \pm g'$.
- $(f \pm g)(x + h) - (f \pm g)(x) = \bigl[f(x + h) - f(x)\bigr] \pm \bigl[g(x + h) - g(x)\bigr]$.
- $f \pm g = \int f' \pm \int g'$ (in which the integral sign signifies taking an antiderivative).
- $(fg)' = fg' + f'g$.
- $(f/g)' = (gf' - fg')/f^{2}$.

The question becomes: Do you know how to prove each of these?

Comment: Yes thank you. That was the point I wanted to pass and no I don't know how to actually prove them.

Comment: The second is just algebraic rearrangement; the first is similar, but involves limits. The third is essentially a tautology. For the fourth, there's a sneaky add-and-subtract trick:$$\frac{f(x+h) g(x+h) - f(x) g(x)}{h} = \frac{f(x+h) \bigl[g(x+h) - g(x)\bigr] + \bigl[f(x+h) - f(x)\bigr] g(x)}{h}.$$For the fifth, start with the simpler case $f = 1$, then use the fourth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually these  I know, but do you think that for an exercise with the description that I had originally, writing these proofs would be an acceptable answer. Because that's my only worry actually how could I relate dx with f(x) even though they are both functions in this case, kind of.

Comment: Checking with your professor is a good idea. Presumably the intent is that $x = f(u)$ and $y = g(u)$, so $dx = f'(u)\, du$ and $dy = g'(u)\, du$, etc., in which case each differential identity follows from the corresponding derivative identity.